# I am unable to download the OSGEO4w installer from its official site

Tags: gis, gdal, geodjango, osgeo

Every time I try to click on the link to download it on the page [(this is the link I am trying to donwload it from.)](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/)

But when I try to download it from the list of all the older versions I get a huge list of options and I dont know which to download it form.[(link that has the list of all older versions.)](http://download.osgeo.org/qgis/win64/)

Comment: Do no select expert install. You are in the wrong site: your question is not about programming. Maybe our GIS sister site (see link in top right icon) may be more relevant.

Comment: did you try http://download.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/v2/osgeo4w-setup.exe

Answer (score 3):

I found out that the link to download it was not working because I was on chrome but even if I go on some other browser and try to install it, it would download the 32 bit version. So I downloaded it from [here](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html).

Also [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mriGWXt_tGk) helped.